# Is there any way to render javascript in email body. using any service SMTP or other.

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, email, smtpclient

I have stored a chart view in an email. and when i send it as email body. only html elements render. but not javascript. i really need this to render... please if any one know any way. on any server/client/ mailProtocol where i can render this one.. 
here is some code samples. 
**View to string function**

```
public static string RenderRazorViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
        {
            controller.ViewData.Model = model;
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

**Here  email sending**

```
string result = Renderer.RenderRazorViewToString (this, "Index", null);

      using (var message = new MailMessage("daily@gmail.com", "email@gmail.com"))
    {

 message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Subject = "ChartTest";
                message.Body = result ;
                message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
                {
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("daily@gmail.com", "myPassword")
                })
                {
 client.Send(message);
 }

}
```

Comment: Create a page on your website that will render data given inputs, and then store a screenshot of that page in your email instead.

Answer (score 0):

Most email services like Gmail, Yahoo and most email clients Thunderbird, Outlook etc. are not supporting Javascript rendering. And I think it is not logical to support JS on emails for security measures.

To accomplish your goal, you should **pre-render and save your content as an image**. Also for this, you have many options.

**Option 1:** Use a graphic library with "export image" feature and include images on your email.

**Option 2:** Use headless browser technology and take a screenshot of your email content. ([Awesome list of headless browsers](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers))

**Option 3:** (similar to option 1) Develop an endpoint which takes an graphic data (or unique id) and returns an image. In this way you do not need to implement "screenshot" mechanism.

Comment: yes. but i dont know how to use a graphic library which saves image at runtime without laod page(only when i call it in my method) and then attach that image in next line email body....

Comment: Which graphic library/plugin are you using?

Comment: i am using highchart.js to generate chart. activity_gauge actually

Comment: See [this link.](https://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-articles/news/56-improved-image-export-with-phantomjs)